# Let code wait untill AJAX request is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, asynchronous

I have the following code to check if a username already exists. It uses an AJAX-request to another page, this page returns either 1 (username exists) or 0 (username doesn't exist).

```
function checkUsername(username,callback){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/check_username.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {username: username},
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(data){
            switch(data.response){
                case 0:
                    callback(true);
                break;
                case 1:
                    callback(false);
                break;
            }
        }
    });                 
};

var error;  // 'undefined' for now

checkUsername('abc',function(data){
    if(data == false){
        // username exists
        error = true;
    }else{
        // username does not exist
        error = false;
    };
});

if(error == false){
    alert('username does not exist');
}else{
    alert('username exists');
};
```

**Problem**

The code checks if `error = true` (there is an error, ie. the username exists) or `error = false`, but the code keeps on running. It doesn't wait until the AJAX-request in `checkUsername` is done. So it's **always** "username exists" (because `error = undefined`, and if-else then goes to the else-statement).

**Question**

How can I make sure that the code waits until the AJAX-request (the `checkUsername` function) is completely done before going any further.

I have a **"partial"** solution: When I wrap the if-else-statement that checks `error = true`/`false` in a `setTimeout`, it works. The problem is: How many miliseconds? I want to have it as fast as possible. 500ms? What if the AJAX-response is not done then? 1000ms? Isn't that too long?

I think there is a better solution than doing this with a `setTimeout`. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: It's asynchronous, you can't first use a callback, and then on the next line just ignore the callback and assume the data is available, it's still async

Comment: Try checking `console.log(data.response)` and `console.log(typeof data.response)`

Comment: @adeneo That should work. That's a different function.

Comment: Q: Let code wait untill AJAX request is done -  A: set async: false

Comment: ^ Isn't it `async: false`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar - nope, it's `async:true` as default, and one should never set it to `false`

Comment: *Starting with Gecko 30.0 (Firefox 30.0 / Thunderbird 30.0 / SeaMonkey 2.27), synchronous requests on the main thread have been deprecated due to the negative effects to the user experience.* || https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request

Comment: P.S. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wer/archive/2011/08/03/why-you-should-use-xmlhttprequest-asynchronously.aspx

Answer (score 3):

```
if(error == false){
    alert('username does not exist');
}else{
    alert('username exists');
};
```

Currently your above code 
is on top of javascript, it is always being executed whether you call your ajax or not.so put it into other function and call it after calling checkUsername().

```
function checkUsername(username,callback){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/check_username.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {username: username},
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(data){
            switch(data.response){
                case 0:
                    callback(true);
                break;
                case 1:
                    callback(false);
                break;
            }
        }
    });                 
};

var error;  // 'undefined' for now

checkUsername('abc',function(data){
    if(data == false){
        // username exists
        error = true;
    }else{
        // username does not exist
        error = false;
    };
    alertMsg();
});

function alertMsg(){
if(error == false){
    alert('username does not exist');
}else{
    alert('username exists');
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try with async: false on ajax function

> async (default: true)
>   Type: Boolean
>   By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active. As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success().

Comment: Did you even read the text you're quoting? It says that async is deprecated and should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

Set async to FALSE and it will not move until ajax request is completed.

```
function checkUsername(username,callback){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/check_username.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {username: username},
        dataType: 'json',
        async : false,
        success : function(data){
            switch(data.response){
                case 0:
                    callback(true);
                break;
                case 1:
                    callback(false);
                break;
            }
        }
    });                 
};

var error;  // 'undefined' for now

checkUsername('abc',function(data){
    if(data == false){
        // username exists
        error = true;
    }else{
        // username does not exist
        error = false;
    };
});

if(error == false){
    alert('username does not exist');
}else{
    alert('username exists');
};
```

Comment: No one should use it and this is btw deprecated

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem couldn't find any way but this worked for me.

```
function sendAjax(){
var defObj = $.Deferred();
//my ajax code here  
defObj.resolve(ajaxResponse);
return defObj.promise();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX (and a lot of other functionality of JavaScript) works asynchonous, this means you do not wait for something to happen but rater tell JavaScript what to do when something happens. In your example you're trying to wait 'till the AJAX-Request finished but what you should do is tell JavaScript to execute your code when the request finished, this means, put the code in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

> Even though you have used callbacks for AJAX, the way you are checking
>   conditions is still asynchronous..

```
checkUsername('abc',function(data){
    alermsg(data);
});

function alertmsg(data){
  !data?alert('username does not exist'):alert('username exists');
}
```